# Is UpgradeMedia Function of PowerPoint 2010 Customizable?

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

I'm looking at the [UpgradeMedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff744739.aspx) new function in PowerPoint 2010 VBA and want to know if there are any details available about 1. Is it customizable (the output) and 2. What exact media it will upgrade. I haven't found too many details on it, does anyone have any?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to customize it.